# Sencha local mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sencha-touch

is it possible to include a MySQL server inside a Sencha App?
So that the Server runs with the App and allows to store data with MySQL queries?
Or is there already an Server available on most Systems?

I'm about to Port a MySQL-based Application to mobile devices and i don't want to completly redo the Database-System part again.

Comment: Does it have to be MySQL specifically or are you just wanting to use a SQL-based relational database?

Comment: No, I'd prefer MySQL, but i'd be okay with any other SQL System.

Comment: ok, thanks i will have a look at it